# AlarmManager, Service, onStartCommand called but unable to start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have the Problem that I created a Service which should be created when the AlarmManager wakes up. And actually it's starting (onStartCommand **is called**, *I see the toast*), but same time in the log appears:

```
    09-19 02:48:32.537: I/ActivityManager(1983): START {flg=0x4 cmp=com.my.app/.syncService.SyncService (has extras)} from pid -1
    09-19 02:48:39.662: W/ActivityManager(1983): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.my.app.syncService.SyncService flg=0x4 (has extras) }: not found
```

Intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.app.syncService.SyncService");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*30, pendingIntent);
```

my Service looks like this:

```
public class SyncService extends Service{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("SyncService", "onCreate");
        Log.d("SyncService", "onCreate");
        Log.d("SyncService", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debug: SyncService created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debug: SyncService onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
   <application>
       ...
       <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.my.app.syncService.SyncService"/>       
   </application>
```

Isn't it a bit strange? The onCreate get's only called once, which makes sense to me, but the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try change this line

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.app.syncService.SyncService");
```

To

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context,SyncService.class);
```

Here, the `context` depends on where you create the `AlarmManager`

Comment: Don't know why, I thought I had it like this before. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml. Something like this:

```
    <receiver android:name="SyncReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.my.app.syncService.SyncService""/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.app.syncService.SyncService");
```

the constructor of Intent class reference intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml